# Remove rows from numpy array when its repeated less than n times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation

**Remove rows from numpy array when its repeated less than n times**

**Cause:**

I have a certain dataset that is 1 gb in size.
It has  29.118.021 samples and 108.390 classes.

However, some classes has just 1 sample. Or 3 samples, and so on...

**Problem:**
I want to remove the rows/classes from the numpy array that are presented/repeated less than N times.

**Reference**
[XgBoost : The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240195/xgboost-the-least-populated-class-in-y-has-only-1-members-which-is-too-few)

**Attempt that failed**

```
train_x, train_y, test_x, test_id = loader.load()

n_samples = train_y.shape[0]
unique_labels, y_inversed = np.unique(train_y, return_inverse=True)
label_counts = bincount(y_inversed)
min_labels = np.min(label_counts)

print "Total Rows ", n_samples
print "unique_labels ", unique_labels.shape[0]
print "label_counts ", label_counts[:]
print "min labels ", min_labels

unique_labels = unique_labels.astype(np.uint8)
unique_amounts = np.empty(shape=unique_labels.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for u in xrange(0, unique_labels.shape[0]):
    if u % 100 == 0:
        print "Processed ", str(u)
    for index in xrange(0, train_y.shape[0]):
        if train_y[index] == unique_labels[u]:
            unique_amounts[u] = unique_amounts[u] + 1

for k in xrange(0, unique_amounts.shape[0]):
    if unique_amounts[k] == 1:
        print "\n"
        print "value :", unique_amounts[k]
        print "at ", k
```

The code above is taking too long.Even after i left it running at the server for 1 whole night, it didnt even reach half processment.

---

**Load method**

This is my load method.
I could load it and keep it as a dataframe.

```
def load():
    train = pd.read_csv('input/train.csv', index_col=False, header='infer')
    test = pd.read_csv('input/test.csv', index_col=False, header='infer')

    # drop useless columns
    train.drop('row_id', axis=1, inplace=True)

    acc = train["accuracy"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    x = train["x"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    y = train["y"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    time = train["time"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    train_y = train["place_id"].iloc[:].as_matrix()

    ####################################################################################
    acc = acc.reshape(-1, 1)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    time = time.reshape(-1, 1)
    train_y = train_y.reshape(-1, 1)

    ####################################################################################

    train_x = np.hstack((acc, x, y, time))

    ####################################################################################

    acc = test["accuracy"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    x = test["x"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    y = test["y"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    time = test["time"].iloc[:].as_matrix()
    test_id = test['row_id'].iloc[:].as_matrix()

    #######################
    acc = acc.reshape(-1, 1)
    x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
    time = time.reshape(-1, 1)
    #######################

    test_x = np.hstack((acc, x, y, time))

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_id
```

Comment: A class or label has only a meaning for a dataframe, not a numpy array

Comment: Well i can load it as a dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) contains a multiplicity function, which leads to a very readable way of performing such manipulations:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
samples_mask = npi.multiplicity(train_y) >= n_min
filtered_train_y = train_y[samples_mask]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it will sure help others with the same issue!

Comment: i will be using this numpy-indexed implementation. Thanks!

Comment: There's an issue though. if i remove the row 'r' from train_y array, i must also remove the row 'r' from train_x   , any ideas?

Comment: Just add `filtered_train_x = train_x[samples_mask]`

Answer (score 1):

I would keep your data in a dataframe format.
That way, you can use some useful methods from the `pandas` module, and that should be quicker than looping.

First, get the different labels associated with `df` with `df['labels'].value_counts()`.
(I assume that the labels column name is `'labels'`).

Then, get only the labels that have less than `n_min` rows in the dataframe.

```
vc = df['labels'].value_counts()
labels = vc[vc < n_min].index
df.drop(labels, inplace=True)
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it will sure help others with the same issue!