# Error using StratifiedShuffleSplit python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shuffle

I don't know why after while my code doesn't work, I am sure it was ok before

I'm trying to use simple `StratifiedShuffleSplit` but it doesn't work

**Code**:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

print(data_x.shape)`
```

(100,1)

`print(data_y.shape)`

(100,28)

consider that my data_y is multi y label

```
stratified_split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, test_size=0.33)
for train_index, test_index in stratified_split.split(data_x, data_y):
    x_train, x_test = data_x[train_index], data_x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = data_y[train_index], data_y[test_index]
```

I get this

**error**:

> ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.`

Could someone please help me?

python3.6 - anaconda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XgBoost : The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is too few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240195/xgboost-the-least-populated-class-in-y-has-only-1-members-which-is-too-few)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly , you have made a mistake when dividing the data , into training and testing samples.

You can somewhat resolve this issue by setting the parameters of `StratifiedShuffleSplit()`,
 as `n_splits=classnum, test_size=testRatio,train_size=1-testRatio, random_state=0`.

Or, you can carefully try and split , the training and testing samples beforehand , and then feed it to `StratifiedShuffleSplit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check `data.column_name.value_counts()` It will tell you the `number of samples for a category`. But as error says, you have only one observation of a category. and if there is only one observation of a `category`, you should remove that observation. Keeping one won't make a difference or add more data for that `category`.